# Defining configuration values under specific namespaces?

Tags: php, arrays, configuration, namespaces, global

I'm writing a framework, and have just added namespaces. I've had no trouble converting everything, save for configuration values.

I can define constants easily, so single values are not a problem...but what about an array of values?

Take this array, for instance, which is the configuration array to add a connection to Capsule...

```
[
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'DB_NAME',
    'username'  => 'USERNAME',
    'password'  => 'PASSWORD',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'prefix'    => ''
  ]
```

I have been using a file that looks like this for database configuration...

```
<?php

  namespace BareBones;

  use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

  $BareBonesCapsule = new Capsule;

  $BareBonesCapsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'DB_NAME',
    'username'  => 'USERNAME',
    'password'  => 'PASSWORD',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'prefix'    => ''
  ]);

  $BareBonesCapsule->setAsGlobal();
  $BareBonesCapsule->bootEloquent();

  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint as Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
```

I'm going to start booting Eloquent from my main `App` class. This will prevent a global variable from doing it. While it is unlikely that `$BareBonesCapsule` is going to be used, I would still like to keep my framework clean and keep everything in it's namespace.

I could declare a bunch of constants in the configurations file...

```
<?php

  namesapce BareBones;

  define("driver", "mysql");
  define("host", "localhost");
  define("database", "DB_NAME");
  /* etc... */
```

This doesn't seem very clean, and I'm assuming there is a better way to do this. How do other frameworks handle this issue, and what alternative means of configuration do I have while maintaining a separation from the global namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .ini files and break them into sections like so:

```
; This is a sample configuration file
; Comments start with ';', as in php.ini

[first_section]
one = 1
five = 5
animal = BIRD

[second_section]
path = "/usr/local/bin"
URL = "http://www.example.com/~username"

[third_section]
phpversion[] = "5.0"
phpversion[] = "5.1"
phpversion[] = "5.2"
phpversion[] = "5.3"

urls[svn] = "http://svn.php.net"
urls[git] = "http://git.php.net"
```

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Symfony supports XML, PHP and YML and allows you to write your own config decoder.